# SSIS - Insert result set from stored proc into table on another DB server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I think I have stumbled upon an edge-case where neither ADO.NET Data Source nor OLDEB Data Source can fully meet my needs:

1. Control Flow -> Execute SQL Task -> ADO.NET Data Source allows handling stored procedures with user-defined tables (table-valued parameters) as parameters.

   - However, I don't have a way/know how to then insert the data into a table on another server.
2. Data Flow -> OLEDB Data Source allows piping the results of a data source on one server directly into the data source on another server.

   - However, all Data Flow sources (OLEDB Data Source or even ADO.NET Data Source) do not appear to allow passing in Parameter Mapping, and therefore have no way to pass in a complex user-defined type.
   - I also cannot use Variable Expressions, because there doesn't appear to be a way to insert an Object as an Expression Value.

Server1 has the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[OrderKeyList] AS TABLE(
  [OrderKey] [varchar](50) NULL
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrdersInOrderList] (
  @OrderList dbo.OrderKeyList not null
)
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT o.*
  FROM dbo.Orders o
  WHERE o.OrderKey in (SELECT o.OrderKey FROM @OrderList);
END
GO
```

SSIS Package is as follows:

```
.-[Sequence Container]-----------------------------------------------.
|                                                                    |
| .-[Data Flow Task - Populate User Variable User::OrderList]-.      |
| |                                                           |      |
| '-----------------------------------------------------------'      |
|                               |                                    |
|                              \|/                                   |
| .-[Execute SQL Task - call dbo.GetOrdersByOrderList]--------.      |
| |                                                           |      |
| '-----------------------------------------------------------'      |
|                               |                                    |
|                              \|/                                   |
| .-[ ?????????????????????????????????????? ]----------------.      |
| |                                                           |      |
| '-----------------------------------------------------------'      |
'--------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

The only solution I can think of is to add a second stored procedure on the Source DB, which takes a @OrderList varchar(max) instead of a dbo.OrderKeyList table, and calls a dbo.Split(',',@OrderList) and passes that to the real stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrdersInOrderListWrapper] (
   @OrderList varchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @tmpOrderList dbo.OrderKeyList
  SELECT
    DISTINCT CAST(o.Data as varchar(50))
  INTO @tmpOrderList
  FROM dbo.Split(',', @OrderList) o;

  EXEC dbo.GetAllOrdersInOrderList @tmpOrderList
END;
GO
```

But I really dislike this approach, because:

- How will it scale to thousands of rows?
- It requires the stored procedure source to add another stored procedure, just for SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching some more, I found a [suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/56032/35450) on Stack Overflow which pointed me to this article by [@Jon Seigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164901/jon-seigel) -- [Using table-valued parameters in SSIS](http://voluntarydba.com/post/2012/12/05/Using-table-valued-parameters-in-SSIS.aspx).

The net-net of it is to pass the User::OrderList as a parameter to a Script Task, and write a C# program to use ADO.NET directly, thereby bypassing the limitations of SSIS GUI.

Why would you want to do it this way?  Why not just write everything in C#?  Well, by doing it this way, I personally still see the benefit of SSIS, in that the overall orchestration of the ETL process is still graphical and so should be very easy to read, even if it is more painful to write (Ha! when is SSIS not painful to write?).

I am trying this approach now, as I can see multiple benefits, including the option in the future to use C# SqlBulkCopy class to bulk insert the data for faster loads.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with the Control Flow / Execute SQL Task approach, you can move the data to a table on another server via a Linked Server.

If you go with the wrapper stored procedure approach you mentioned, it won't scale horribly for an ETL process, even at thousands of rows.  If it were me, this is the option I would go with.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be related to trying to pass an object as a user defined type, I have never tried passing a 'table' as a parameter.

I would do this:
Instead of pushing data to an object variable push it to a table, possibly temp, on the source.  Your stored procedure can be run with the name of the table as a parameter and then execute a dynamic sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllOrdersInOrderList] (
  @OrderList varchar(500) not null
)
AS
BEGIN    
Set @Sql = '  SELECT o.*
      FROM dbo.Orders o
      WHERE o.OrderKey in (SELECT o.OrderKey FROM ' + @OrderList +')';
    Exec @Sql
END
```

Maybe someone else has a way to do it exactly as you describe, I will be very interested to see such a solution myself.